# C++ How to Fix redefiniton without changin the function or linked CPP files?

Tags: c++, redefinition

I am fairly new to C++ and trying to get used to it after learning Java. For an assignment, I was given two different CPP files both containing many different functions but are not classes. I have to create the main function using some functions from these CPP files. I included one of the files and managed to access the functions. However, once I included the second CPP file, I realized that both CPP files have some static functions in common with different implementations. Since I can't change the files nor add a header file, I can't get rid of the redefinition problem. Any answer will help.

PS: I didn't want to add the code or be more specific since this is an assignment and I don't want to access more than the conceptual aspect.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't have to have a header file to declare functions.

Comment: **NEVER** include *.cpp files. It also seems like you are misunderstanding the assignment.

Comment: You do *not* include cpp files in one another. You only include headers.

Comment: You need to present a [mcve] if you want to get help, because we cannot fix code we cannot see. If you "don't want to" provide that information, then I'm afraid we cannot help you. Consider having a conversation with your teacher, instead; that's what they're there for.

Comment: If you're using gcc, simply give the command `g++ -o output file name <all files to be linked>` -O2

Comment: But do present a minimal reproducible example, as @AsteroidsWithWings has suggested. (Anyone knows the shortcut to insert the user-name after typing @? Its so annoying to reach out all the way to the mouse just to click)

Comment: *and trying to get used to it after learning Java* -- Another piece of advice - do **not** write or learn C++ using Java as a model.  You will get even more confused and bedazzled.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 After a few characters you can tab-complete. You only need three characters to get a notification anyway

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie some website materials pointed out that developers can hide some strings or key using C++ in android app developing, so some people may try to learn some c++ after learning java.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with learning C++ and Java.  The problem is when Java techniques are used to write C++ programs.  You see it here many times, where the Java person who has not learned C++ properly creates C++ programs that are buggy, inefficient, full of memory leaks, or the program just looks strange to a regular C++ programmer.